# How do I set the focal node in a D3.js Force Directed Graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a data set that defines a number of nodes to use in a Force Directed Graph.  It looks like...

```
  var nodeSet = [
    {id: "N1", name: "Node 1", type: "Type 1", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com"},
    {id: "N2", name: "Node 2", type: "Type 3", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/glossary.html"},
    {id: "N3", name: "Node 3", type: "Type 4", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/resources.html"},
    {id: "N4", name: "Node 4", type: "Type 5", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/taxonomy.html"},
    {id: "N5", name: "Node 5", type: "Type 1", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/disciplines.html"}
  ];
```

How do I specifically tell the force.layout in the d3.js library to use "Node 1" of id = "N1" as the primary root or focal node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want a root node you can have a root property in your object and set it to true, than treat that node separately. You can also set this root to center. Here is how we did it (d3 + Prototype - at the time - now switching to d3+jQuery+underscore):

```
getCenter: function() {
    var center = {
        x : this.width / 2,
        y : this.height / 2
    };
    return center;
}

//later do something like this in your init method:
var first = {
                id : id,
                name : name,
                x : this.getCenter().x,
                y : this.getCenter().y,
                root : true,
                //other properties
            };

//later in your redraw() or other methods you might employ...
//try to find the root node later in the code using something like:
var rootNode = this.nodes.detect(function(node) {
    return node.root;
});

//do something to the root node after you have detected it...
if (rootNode) {
    rootNode.x = rootNode.px = this.getCenter().x;
    rootNode.y = rootNode.py = this.getCenter().y;
    //some other stuff...
}
```

This is how we have done it. However it's not clear to me what are the links in your example... A little bit puzzled.
As you will notice, for a force directed layout or more complicated animations you almost always need to use D3+something else (Prototype, jQuery, underscore) for the simple methods like detect or include or other similar Ruby style methods.

Comment: as a side note: when doing any serious force directed layouts you will also need some helper methods to help you place the nodes were you want, to help you filter or draw the nodes in specific ways, and also for the force settings... many of those helper methods will likely use one of the 3 libraries I mentioned :)

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the reply.  Good info on finding the center.  As far as a root node goes, it appears that D3 implicitly uses the first node in the node list (i.e. "Node 1" in the above array of nodes) as its root.  You can see this in the example I've created at [Force Direct Radial Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/2879486).  It doesn't appear that there is an explicit way to tell it to use a different node as its root for the force directed graph. My Best,  Frank

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by focal or root node. If you want to fix a certain node in a specific place (e.g. the centre) you can set its 'fixed' attribute to true. For more info see [Fix Node Position in D3 Force-Directed Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392505/fix-node-position-in-force-directed-layout), and also [Moving fixed nodes in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502877/moving-fixed-nodes-in-d3).

I dont think your [force directed radial graph](http://bl.ocks.org/2879486) example does show that d3 implicitly uses the first node in the node list as the 'root' node. Node 1 in your example always gravitates towards the centre as a consequence of the network structure. If you place Node 1 later in the array of nodes its behaviour is the same.