# d3js create a force layout with fixed nodes

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

i've implemented this http://jsbin.com/omokap/3/edit:

[image]

However, I would like to cancel the dynamic behavior of the graph (like in the dragend state, but that is only for the single node) and place the nodes in the set points, taken from json.

I've see this questions [Moving fixed nodes in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502877/moving-fixed-nodes-in-d3) and [Fix Node Position in D3 Force-Directed Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392505/fix-node-position-in-force-directed-layout).
I did not understand how to use them in my example.

can someone give me a help?

Comment: For the nodes you don't want to move, set the `fixed` property to `true`.

Comment: i've read the other question and relative response and i've make:
 <code>for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
            nodes[i].fixed = true;
            nodes[i].x = function(d) { return d.cx; };
            nodes[i].y = function(d) { return d.cy; };
            nodes[i].px = function(d) { return d.cx; };
            nodes[i].py = function(d) { return d.cy; };
        }</code>

this is the result http://jsbin.com/omokap/4/edit

Comment: @LarsKotthoff where i went wrong?

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me. In principle, your code should achieve what you want.

Comment: Excuse me example doesn't work because i've a problem with IPS and cannot save if add D3js library. I've resolved myself. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the solution is simple insert into the nodes object x,y coordinates and fixed:true like this

```
{ name: "Sara", id:"1", x:239.31191418045182, y:296.78520431471384, fixed:true},
{ name: "Raul", id:"2", x:261.1651006560272, y:200.78448049334696, fixed:true},
{ name: "Stefano", id:"3", fixed:false},
{ name: "Michele", id:"4", fixed:false}
```

this is a working example http://jsbin.com/omokap/8/edit please add yourself d3js library.

for my purpose works fine.